# javascript/php sorting plugin

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, javascript

I have a set of thumbnails and I want to sort them by name, by rating and by newest added.
I've found [Quicksand](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/) which I think is pretty good, but I need to know if there are some other scripts/plugins which does the same job.

Comment: What are you exactly looking for? You already have found a script, but you want to know whether there are others. The question is: why do you want to know this. What don't you like about Quicksand that you are looking for others?

Comment: What PeeHaa said. Just arbitrarily wanting some other options isn't really what the SE sites are for.

Comment: I'm asking because I want to add a filter by number of facebook likes for example... if this is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is server part language, so you can do that with jQuery. Some demos for you.

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo

http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/

You could also search `jquery sort` via google.

Answer (score 0):

I love datatables (see: http://datatables.net/) for sorting and filtering through rows in a table format - if you need to search for text, or between dates submitted, etc.

It is very simple to use, but it's only for data in table format, which may not be what you are looking for. It will automatically convert a designated html table with the proper format on the fly, which makes it server language agnostic and I have used it with everything from custom php to complex Drupal applications, and since this is such a simple way to get the job done, some team members of mine recently used it on a SharePoint project with the same ease.